# Prevent users from editing old contacts

Tags: read-only

In our contacts database we have a checkbox (inactive). When the inactive checkbox is ticked, I don't want the users to make any changes to that record. How would I best achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Possible ways to achieve this are:

**Trigger Or Validation rule.**

You can create a trigger on(before update) contact that if checkbox is checked show error through addError method.

Or simply from validation rule you can throw error.